# header is not working on angular $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

In my **angular app**, I want to use `angular custom header`. I'm using the following code::

**Angular Factory**

```
angular.module('app').factory('UserAPI', ['$resource', 'session',   function($resource, session) {
   var mainUrl = 'http://localhost:8006/dev' + '/users';
   return {
      getService : function() {
        var token = session.getToken();
        console.log(token); //token is printed here
        return $resource(mainUrl, { }, {
           getData: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: mainUrl + '/:userId/dashboard',
                isArray: true,
                headers: { 'Token': token }
            }
         });
      }
   }
}]);
```

**Angular Controller**

```
angular.module('app').controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserAPI',  function($scope, UserAPI) {

    var user = UserAPI.getService();

    user.getData({ userId: 'some-user-id' }, {}, function(res) {

    }, function(err) {

    });
}]);
```

When I make call `user.getUser(......)`, an url is generated as like as **GET::** `http://localhost:8006/dev/user/some-user-id/dashboard` instead of **GET::** `http://localhost:8006/dev/user/some-user-id/dashboard?token=SomeVeryLongToken`, I mean **token** is missing on api call, although I'm using `headers: { 'Token': token }` but still problem.

How can I solve this problem?

**NB** `"angular": "^1.4.0",`
       `"angular-resource": "^1.4.0",`

Comment: If you wanted it to be a queryparam, why are you setting it as a header?

Comment: @KevinB, `queryparam` is for others option and `header` is for `token`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `headers: { 'Token': token }` to `params: { 'token': token }`

Answer (score 0):

You're adding token as a request header, not as a property in the query string. Use the second (in your example empty) object to add parameters, or add them directly in your controller:

```
user.getUser({token: 'sometoken'}, {}, function(res) {

}, function(err) {

});
```